# Dropdownlist Datasource by LINQ Query does not work

Tags: c#, linq

I have a system.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator and it return value like image below
[[image]

But when I add this to list then add to dropdown datasource, it doesn't work

[image]

Please help

and here is my code

```
using (var dr = db.ExecuteDataReader("GetDealersWithDiscount", CommandType.StoredProcedure, param))
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dealers.Add(new Dealer
                {
                    Name = Convert.ToString(dr["dealer_name"]),
                    Adress = Convert.ToString(dr["dealer_address"]),
                    Zipcode = Convert.ToString(dr["dealer_zip_code"]),
                    Image = Convert.ToString(dr["dealer_name"]),
                    Manufacturer = Convert.ToString(dr["manufacturer_id"])
                });
            }

        }
```

## Event

```
string[] zipcodes = strzipcode.Split(',');
List<Dealer> filterList = new List<Dealer>();
filterList.Add(new Dealer
{
    Zipcode = txtZipCode.Text.Trim()
});
for (int x = 0; x < zipcodes.Length-1; x++)
{
    filterList.Add(new Dealer
    {
        Zipcode = zipcodes[x]
    });
}
var filteredFileSet = dealers.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i));
dtlSanPham.DataSource = filteredFileSet.ToList();
dtlSanPham.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please post some code not images

Comment: Please provide more detail such as Winforms/WPF etc. As @Emad mentioned post actual code, and possibly more code.

Comment: Does `Dealer` override `Equals` at all? Otherwise your `Contains` check won't work anyway.

Comment: Seems the filteredFileSet is empty

Comment: Could you maybe increase the scope of the code? Where does the `dealers` var come from?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are creating new dealers in `filterList` with ONLY a zipcode, and then comparing them to dealers in the `dealers` list that has Zipcodes as well as other information (which means they will never match).

Instead of comparing Dealers against dealers, try create a `List<string>` of just zipcodes, and filter on that. In the where clause you will need to reference the string property of the ZipCode class or override `ToString()` in the class to display it. 
[How to override `ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx)

`Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.ZipCode.Value));`

or

`Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.ZipCode.ToString()));`

```
string[] zipcodes = strzipcode.Split(',');
List<string> filterList = new List<string>();
filterList.Add(txtZipCode.Text.Trim());

zipcodes.ForEach(zipCode => {
  filterList.Add(zipCode);
})

var filteredFileSet = dealers.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.ZipCode.Value));
dtlSanPham.DataSource = filteredFileSet.ToList();
dtlSanPham.DataBind();
```

Comment: var filteredFileSet = dealers.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.ZipCode)) doesn't work because filterlist does not contain a definition for zipcode. Thanks any way

Comment: I see, can you override `ToString()` in your ZipCode class to provide the value? Then you can use `Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.ZipCode.ToString()))` which will work. Alternatively what is the string property in the ZipCode class that holds the zipcode value?

Comment: Thank you very much Thematkinson, it work well, you are saving my day

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark as answer if you are happy with the solution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work